# Windows 8 Metro button color changed on rollover

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am building a Metro app. I have set the background color to black and foreground to white. When I build and test and rollover the button it changes its color to white. This is not going to work with my color scheme.

How can I prevent the button from changing colors on rollover?

Thanks

Comment: Figured it out by luck. Had to add a new style to the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You figured out what you need to do for a single button (or a subset of buttons in your app).  If you want to do it for all buttons in your app, however, you can override in app.xaml:

```
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <!-- When not in high contrast mode, use a colorful look. 
                                Note that this is defining an implicit style that is scoped to this StackPanel. -->

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <Thickness x:Key="ButtonBorderThemeThickness">2</Thickness>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF0088B4" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF0088B4" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF7ED1EC" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF0088B4" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FF0088B4" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```